# Rocket.chat video calling not working properly

Tags: chat, rocket.chat

I am seeing my own video in `rocket.chat` instead of the person whom I am chatting with. Do you know what could cause this to happen?

Comment: I am not able to view the person who is chatting with me. I have verified that cameras are working properly.

Comment: Have you gone to https://test.webrtc.org/ and checked that everything works on your test?

Comment: hi @armatita , were you successful? any problem identified or solutions identified? we have issue in iOS/ OSX connection, no video is shown, the button simply does not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @ManoharPoreddy I'm not the person who made the question. I just edited it at some point.

Comment: hi @gokul89 , were you successful? any problem identified or solutions identified? we have issue in iOS/ OSX connection, no video is shown, the button simply does not work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but after upgrade to last version of Rocket.Chat my problem is gone.
So try update your chat instance to latest version, for me it was 0.50.0

Comment: please add a reference to the 'latest version" you refer to.